# Changing host file in Ubuntu

Tags: ip, dns, hosts

I tried to change `/etc/hosts` to change a local DNS entry, so I can map any website name to any IP, but it isn't working. How can I debug it?

Comment: The file name you need to edit is `/etc/hosts` (not `host`). You need root permission to edit the file.

Comment: Can you better explain what it is that you're trying to do with websites?

Comment: @Karlson I am trying to change local dns at my computer so that i can open facebook.com by entering www.google.com in browser and mapping google.com with the ip of facebook.com in hosts file.

Comment: @RahulKumarDubey So you are doing this on the workstation accessing the internet?

Answer (score 4):

Check `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and make sure on the `hosts` line, `files` is the first option and not `dns`

Comment: please explain in detail about /etc/nsswitch.conf and how it is related to /etc/hosts file ??

Comment: @RahulKumarDubey `man nsswitch.conf`